# Reading multiple CSV files from multiple files into pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I would like to go through different csv files contained in different folders in the same directory. My folders are in my working directory. My folders are named:

```
folder1, folder2,folder3
```

each of them have csv's with identical names `csv1.csv, csv2.csv`.

I tried this code:

```
import os
import re
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame

rootDir = '.'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir, topdown=False):
    print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)
    for fname in fileList:
        print('\t%s' % fname)

        if "csv1.csv" == fname:
            var= pd.read_csv(fname)
```

I can print the name of the csv file in that folder but i get an error:
`IOError: File csv1.csv does not exist`
what could be the problem?

Comment: looks like if you are expecting fname to equal 'csv1.csv' you're not passing the path of the file to read_csv.  Probably need something like `pd.read_csv(os.join(path, fname))`

Comment: the path of the whole folder or the path of that csv file?

Comment: if your working directory is `/home/user` and your files are located in `/home/user/dir1, /home/user/dir2...`, you need to at least have the relative path of the file `dir2/csv1.csv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in comments, you have to join `rootDir`, `dirName` and `fname`.

```
import os
import re
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame

rootDir = '.'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir, topdown=False):
    print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)
    for fname in fileList:
        print('\t%s' % fname)
        filepath = os.path.join(rootDir, dirName, fname)
        if "csv1.csv" == fname:
            var = pd.read_csv(filepath)
            print var.head()
```

[os.path.join(path, *paths)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html):

> Join one or more path components intelligently. The return value is the concatenation of path and any members of `*paths` with exactly one directory separator (`os.sep`) following each non-empty part except the last, meaning that the result will only end in a separator if the last part is empty. If a component is an absolute path, all previous components are thrown away and joining continues from the absolute path component.
>
> On Windows, the drive letter is not reset when an absolute path component (e.g., `r'\foo'`) is encountered. If a component contains a drive letter, all previous components are thrown away and the drive letter is reset. Note that since there is a current directory for each drive, `os.path.join("c:", "foo")` represents a path relative to the current directory on drive `C:` (`c:foo`), not `c:\foo`.

Comment: thank you very much; i have a question though, it it seems to only read about 7000 rows but the data i have contains around 50000 rows for each csv; what is the issue here?

Comment: actually it was fine; i actually asked the wrong question; as  it only keeps a copy of the last csv five in my var, i actually wanted to concatenate it all the columns for each csv read from the directory; that is my var should contain the column of both csv file

Comment: you can create empty df and append one column of data from csv's - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32352211/sorting-by-groups/32353725#32353725, but you have to change for adding column `code` : `df = pd.DataFrame()` and `df = df.append(g['code'].tolist(), ignore_index=True)`